# How to unmarshall response in jaxb

Tags: apache, xml-parsing, jaxb, cxf

I am facing major problem in my project.
we have 2 xsd's. One is request xsd and another is response xsd. I have created JAXB classes for both xsd's.

I pass the Request JAXB to service layer then i got response object. Now i want to unmarshall this response as per Response JAXB.

So pleas help me to resolve this issue in my project. It is more appreciable.

Regards
Narsi

Comment: could you elaborate what content type you are using ? what errors you are getting...etc also your cxf version

Comment: response as JSON object?

Comment: i am using cxf version 2.6. Just i read request JAXB which contains the data of project specific . I am getting unmarshall exception ..

Comment: What exception are you getting? Provide us with your XSD and the exception you get.

Answer (score 2):

The below code snippet will help you.

```
File file = new File("Customers.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customers.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Customers customers = (Customers) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

You said you have got the output XML. so pass it in the place of customers.xml. You have also mentioned that you have created the java objects from the xsd. So pass that class name in place of Customers.class.

You dont have to import any new jars as all these classes are present in rt.jar

Hope this helps you.